# String keeps initializing as null

Tags: java

My string keeps initializing itself as null... or at least it seems that way. I am trying to make a custom toString function for my matrix. `this.matrixArray` is a 2D array of dimensions 'm x n'.

```
public String toString() {
    String stringAsMatrix = "";
    String dimensions = this.m + "," + this.n + "\n";
    stringAsMatrix += dimensions;
    String[] dataRows = new String[this.m];

    for (int row = 0; row < this.m; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < this.n; column++) {
            String elementString = "";
            elementString += this.matrixArray[row][column];
            if (column == this.n-1) {
                dataRows[row] += elementString + "\n";
            } else {
                dataRows[row] += elementString + ","; // Only add a comma if this isn't the last element in the row
            }
        }
        stringAsMatrix += dataRows[row];
    }
    return stringAsMatrix;
}
```

This is the output I get but I don't understand why it prints 'null' before my string. The dimensions are correct (the matrix array is indeed 2x2). The values themselves are also correct `(my matrix is {{1,2}, {3,4}})`

```
2,2
null1.0,2.0
null3.0,4.0
```

Comment: When you make a `new String[this.m]`, it starts out full of nulls. Same with any array of a non-primitive type.

Comment: Also, building strings with `+=` in a loop is a really inefficient way to do things.

Comment: @user2357112 `+=` actually compiles to use a `StringBuilder`, which is efficient, behind the scenes, as can be seen with `javap -c Classname`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex: It uses a StringBuilder, sure. And then the next `+=` uses a new StringBuilder, and the next `+=` uses yet another StringBuilder. If it saved one StringBuilder and used it across the whole `column` loop, it could work in linear time, but it can't do that. It has to slowly copy the accumulated String into a new StringBuilder every time, causing degradation to quadratic time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataRows[row] += elementString + "\n";
```

`dataRows[row]` is starting out with `null` in it.  So it becomes

```
dataRows[row] = null + elementString + "\n"
```

...which is exactly what you get.  Instead, write

```
dataRows[row] = elementString + "\n";
```

Comment: I am so stupid. Thanks a ton for the super quick help.